# How do I enforce mutually-exclusive properties in two sibling objects using JSON schema?

Tags: jsonschema

I have a JSON object with two constant properties - `foo` and `bar`. The values are also objects with arbitrary keys. How do I assert, using JSON schema, that the properties of the `foo` and `bar` objects are mutually exclusive?

For instance, this is a good (=should pass validation) object, because `foo` has properties `a, b` while `bar` has properties `c, d`:

```json
{
    "foo": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
    },

    "bar": {
        "c": 3,
        "d": 4
    }
}
```

While this is a bad (=should fail validation) object, because both `foo` and `bar` have property `a` in them:

```json
{
    "foo": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
    },

    "bar": {
        "c": 3,
        "a": 4
    }
}
```

Notice `a, b, c` were just arbitrarily used - I don't require any of these properties, only that if they appear in one object they shall not appear in the other (and vice versa). Also - there are only two objects `foo`, `bar` and not an arbitrarily long list of objects.

Here's a simple schema (modified from the one generated using [`genson`](https://pypi.org/project/genson/)) that would validate both the good and bad examples above (because the constraint is missing):

```json
{'$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/schema#',
 'type': 'object',
 'properties': {
  'foo': {'type': 'object'},
  'bar': {'type': 'object'}},
 'required': ['bar', 'foo']
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible using JSON Schema.

Comment: @Relequestual 
 I could store as 
```
{
  "a": {
   "value": 1,
   "type": "a"
  },
  "b": {
 "value": 2,
 "type": "b"
  },
  "c": {
 "value": 3,
 "type": "a"
  }
}
```
But hoped I could avoid this!

Comment: You can use other things to validate your data =] JSON Schema is awesome, but it's not designed to cover all business logic use cases.